# JPA Query using a Map as Input?

Tags: sql, spring, kotlin, jpa

I have a Kotlin Map: Map<String, <String, String>>

And I have a JPA-Query.
Is it possible to Select a value depending on the Query?

for Example:  `SELECT Map[a.val] FROM SomeRepo a WHERE a.otherval<100`

Answer (score 0):

The JPA specification (4.4.4 Path Expressions) lists KEY,VALUE and ENTRY key words you can use to access the map-valued element collection values as path expressions. Example from the spec:

```
SELECT i.name, VALUE(p)
FROM Item i JOIN i.photos p
WHERE KEY(p) LIKE ‘%egret’
```